# Integrating $\frac{x^3}{\exp(x)-1}$ from $0$ to $\infty$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

While doing Physics and trying to prove the law of Stefan-Boltzmann from Plancks-law one comes to the integral 
\[ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{\exp(x)-1}  \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^4}{15} \]
and I would like to know how one calculates this value. One could try integration by parts to get rid of the $x^3$ part, but as Mathematica says the anti derivative is not very simple (there are some polylogarithms involved). Does anyone have an idea how to solve the Integral?

Comment: You can start by utilizing the following geometric series formula to integrate term by term: $$ \frac{1}{e^x - 1} = e^{-x} + e^{-2x} + e^{-3x} + \cdots.$$

Comment: In general, $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}~dx~=~n!\cdot\zeta(n+1),$$ and $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}~dx~=~n!\cdot\eta(n+1).$$ See the [Riemann $\zeta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) functions for more information.

Comment: @Lucian The method I used herein can be used to show this result inductively as repeated integration by parts leads the way forward!  A neat problem!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will continue along Lee's comment to produce a full answer.

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^{x}-1}dx$

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^\infty x^3(e^{-x}+e^{-2x}+\ldots)dx$

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^\infty x^3e^{-x}dx+\int_0^\infty x^3e^{-2x}dx+\ldots$

Now,

$\displaystyle A=\int_0^\infty x^m e^{-nx} dx$

Let $x=\frac{u}{n},\ dx=\frac{1}{n}du$. Then,

$\displaystyle A=\frac{1}{n^{m+1}}\int_0^\infty u^m e^{-u}du = \frac{m!}{n^{m+1}}  $

Thus, we get

$\displaystyle I=3!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{4}}$

$\displaystyle I=6\zeta(4)$

However, we know that $\displaystyle \zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$

Thus, $\displaystyle I=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$

Comment: Very well done!  I evaluated along a different way forward and, of course, obtained the same result.  I never take for granted how fascinating analysis really is whereby two distinct approaches yield the same result!

Comment: Well, to be fully honest, I can't say I understand your answer. I haven't learned such stuff yet, so yeah. :P

Comment: As it turns out, the Riemann-Zeta function is related to the Polylogarithm Function.  In fact $\text{Li}_s(1)=\zeta(s)$.  If you're interested, have a look at the references, following the embedded links included in my post.  It's really cool stuff, I believe.

Comment: What I mean is that I haven't had a proper introduction to the zeta function and the polylogarithm functions. Sorry, but I'm still pretty much a beginner in math :p

Comment: No apology.  You're doing quite well, especially given that you're a "beginner."  ;-))

Answer (score 2):

Here, we develop an alternative, straightforward  approach that makes use of the Polylogarithm Functions.  To that end, we start with the integral

$$I\equiv\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$$

and enforce the substitution $x\to -\log (1-x)$ with $dx\to \frac{1}{1-x}dx$ to obtain

$$I=-\int_0^{1}\frac{(\log (1-x))^3}{x}dx$$

Next , we enter into a series of three integration by parts.

First, integration by parts with $u=(\log (1-x))^3$ and $v=\log x$ yields

$$I=-3\int_0^1 (\log (1-x))^2 \frac{\log x}{1-x}\,dx$$

Upon the second integration by parts with $u=(\log (1-x))^2$ and $v=\text{Li}_2(1-x)$, where $\text{Li}_2(x)\equiv\int_0^x \frac{\log (1-t)}{t}dt$ is the [Dilogarithm Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function), we obtain

$$I=-6\int_0^1 \log (1-x) \frac{\text{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx$$

And finally, a third and final integration by parts with $u=\log (1-x)$ and $v=\text{Li}_3(1-x)$, where $\text{Li}_3(x)\equiv\int_0^x \frac{\text{Li}_2 (1-t)}{t}dt$ is a [Polylogarithm Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), reveals

$$\begin{align}
I&=6\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_3(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx\\\\
&=-6\left.\text{Li}_4(1-x)\right|_0^1\\\\
&=6\text{Li}_4(1)\\\\
&=6\zeta(4)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{15}
\end{align}$$

as expected, where we have used [The Relationship $\text{Li}_s(1)=\zeta(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions), between the polylogarithm function and the [Riemann-Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Generalizations).

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I evaluated the integral using a straightforward approach that only relies on use of polylogarithm functions and the identity $\text{Li}_s(1)=\zeta (s)$.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.